# How to debug Call to a member function dispatch() on null ininternal\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action.php on line 91

Tags: magento2

I am getting

> Call to a member function dispatch() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_6\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action.php on line 91

How to debug the error?  i wont get any logs!!

Doesnt enter the `execute()` of the controller

**my etc/module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.2.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
        <module name="Vendor_Module2"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

**etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="merchandisingpage" frontName="merchandisingpage">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

**Controller/Result/Index**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $tglssearchClientConnector;

public function __construct( 
    // \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    /*\Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory $queryFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, */
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Vendor_Module3\Model\Client\Connector $tglssearchClientConnector,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $catalogCategoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory 
)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->layout = $layout;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->tglssearchClientConnector = $tglssearchClientConnector;
    $this->catalogCategoryFactory = $catalogCategoryFactory;
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->resultPageFactory=$resultPageFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please uncomment below line in your constructor call

```
// \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
```

and add below parent constructor call in your constructor function

```
parent::__construct($context);
```

Comment: Is  including the class Context mandate or in what scenarios we have to include the same?

Comment: I think this will help you to understand contex object [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108163/what-is-context-object-purpose-in-any-classs-constructor-di-how-context-works]