# Magento 2 Incorrect dependency in class already exists in context object

Tags: magento2, error, varnish, testing, marketplace

I created a extension submitted for approval
On my local there is Varnish cashe enabled but `sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile` runs without any error.

**I got 6 errors in Technical Report**

`Environment`: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 7.0.28, Magento Platform - 2.0.17 CE Varnish, Sampla Data

`Command:` setup:di:compile

```
Installation issue:  Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 42.0 MiB
                     -------- some more lines than
                     Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---] 85% 36 secs 232.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
Companyname\Modulename\Block\HomehorizontalWidget
Incorrect dependency in class Companyname\Modulename\Block\HomehorizontalWidget in /var/www/html/vendor/Companyname/Modulename/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data
Incorrect dependency in class Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data in /var/www/html/vendor/Companyname/Modulename/Helper/Data.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 2
Errors during compilation:
Companyname\Modulename\Block\HomehorizontalWidget
Incorrect dependency in class Companyname\Modulename\Block\HomehorizontalWidget in /var/www/html/vendor/Companyname/Modulename/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data
Incorrect dependency in class Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data in /var/www/html/vendor/Companyname/Modulename/Helper/Data.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 2
Errors during compilation:
Companyname\Modulename\Block\HomehorizontalWidget
Incorrect dependency in class Companyname\Modulename\Block\HomehorizontalWidget in /var/www/html/vendor/Companyname/Modulename/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem already exists in context object
Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data
Incorrect dependency in class Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data in /var/www/html/vendor/Companyname/Modulename/Helper/Data.php
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface already exists in context object
Total Errors Count: 2

Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 40 secs 232.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
```

`file` : /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Companyname/Reviews/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php

```
   <?php
    namespace Companyname\Reviews\Block;

    #File: app/code/Companyname/Reviews/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php

    class HomehorizontalWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         * @var \Companyname\Reviews\Helper\Data
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
         * @var  \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
         *
         */

        protected $_helper;
        protected $jsonHelper;
        protected $_filesystem;
        protected $_imageFactory;
        protected $_registry;

        /**
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
         * @param array                                            $data
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry                      $registry
         * @param \Companyname\Reviews\Helper\Data                      $helper
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data              $jsonHelper
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem                    $filesystem
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory          $imageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            array $data = [],
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Companyname\Reviews\Helper\Data $helper,
            \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
            \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);

            $this->_helper       = $helper;
            $this->jsonHelper    = $jsonHelper;
            $this->_filesystem   = $filesystem;
            $this->_registry     = $registry;
            $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        }
..................
```

Update :After removing `_filesystem` i got below fatal error

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Reviews\Block;

class HomehorizontalWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_helper;
    protected $jsonHelper;
    //protected $_filesystem;  removed
    protected $_imageFactory;
    protected $_registry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Companyname\Reviews\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        // \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, removed
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_helper       = $helper;
        $this->jsonHelper    = $jsonHelper;
       // $this->_filesystem   = $filesystem; removed
        $this->_registry     = $registry;
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
    }
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 6 passed to Companyname\Reviews\Block\HomehorizontalWidget::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\Filesystem given, called in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Companyname/Reviews/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Companyname\Reviews\Block\HomehorizontalWidget->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Registry), Object(Companyname\Reviews\Helper\Data), Object(Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data), Object(Magento\Framework\Filesystem), Object(Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory)) #1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Companyname\\Rev in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Companyname/Reviews/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php on line 29
```

Comment: It seems like you are injecting stuff that is already included in context.

Comment: can i share the constructor HomehorizontalWidget.php

Comment: Have a look at the error. It tells you all the classes that are already in the context object.

Comment: i shared on of the file , can you plz see

Comment: Do i need to remove those lines `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem` ?

Comment: Yes have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is clear on what is wrong. Its complaining that you're inject classes that are already in the context object. Have a look at [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108163/what-is-context-object-purpose-in-any-classs-constructor-di-how-context-works) for a better understanding of what the context is.

> Context objects were introduced to isolate third party developers from
>   changes in constructors of abstract classes.

You need to remove these two classes you are injecting into the block and helper classes and instead use what is already included in the context class.

```
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem 

\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
```

Instead just call `$context->getFilesystem()` and `$this->scopeConfig`

Comment: i removed  protected $_filesystem; ,  \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, and  $this->_filesystem   = $filesystem; , now it gives me another error in local envirnment

Comment: i have no idea about the use of `_filesystem` here,  is it necessary to use this in block , i took help form other sources

Comment: .... If you're not using it then why include it in the first place? Its always good to understand what the code does instead of just copying and pasting.

Comment: yes i understood that i must read understand before copy, currently i am not using `_filesystem` anywhere in the file after `__construct`

Comment: i think _filesystem is used as once i am trying to create a funtionality related to `imageFactory` now that functionality  is removed so i need to remove the both classes 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/magento-2-how-to-get-resize-image-for-custom-module

Comment: because after removing `filesystem` and `imageFactory` website and extension working normally

Comment: thank you for your help, from now onward i will first understand what the code exactly does