# Why is parent::__construct($context) used?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependency, construct

I have experience in programming with php and i think i have a good understanding of what a constructor does. But in Magento the constructor is called with the implemented Dependency's but after that the parent::__construct is also called and that has some parameters, but i can't seem to understand why these parameters are there and why you would need the parrent constructor or is it the constructor called in the same file i don't know so me be some one can explain it to this nood haha

this is an example

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );
}
```

Comment: Here is the answers, i think it is duplicated https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108163/what-is-context-object-purpose-in-any-classs-constructor-di-how-context-works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we extends the class and that class have

> __construct

and that assign some default value to the methods and variable.

So for the same things we are using this code here.